# android notification remoteInput display issue

Tags: android, notifications

we used the direct reply functionality for Android 7, so users can reply to chatmessages via the received pushnotification. When they were editing the reply message, they received a new push message. At this time, the input box will block the notification content.

Here's my code:

```
    String replyLabel = getResources().getString(R.string.reply_label);
    RemoteInput remoteInput = new RemoteInput.Builder(KEY_TEXT_REPLY)
            .setLabel(replyLabel)
            .build();

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GetMessageReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Notification.Action replyAction = new Notification.Action.Builder(
            R.drawable.ic_chat_blue_24dp, 
            getString(R.string.label), pendingIntent)
            .addRemoteInput(remoteInput)
            .build();

    Notification newMessageNotification = new 
    Notification.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_account_circle_white_24dp)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.title))
            .setContentText(getString(R.string.content))
            .addAction(replyAction)
            .build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = 
         (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, newMessageNotification);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbvUT.jpg)